# How to display first three characters in employee name in lower case and remaining characters in upper case in sql

Tags: sql

I need an answer for the above question

Comment: What's the time limit on your test?

Comment: SUBSTRING the first 3 and LOWER them, and then SUBSTRING the rest and UPPER them, then!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `UPPER()` & `LOWER()` function if you are working with Microsoft SQL Server

```
DECLARE @DATA NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'xxxyyy'

SELECT @DATA

SELECT CONCAT(UPPER(LEFT(@DATA, 3)), LOWER(SUBSTRING(@DATA, 4, LEN(@DATA))))
```

Result :

```
XXXyyy
```